# Problems with texlive 2022 and memoir class

Tags: memoir, texlive2022

I have a simple TeX document test.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\begin{document}

This is a test

\end{document}
```

If I run pdflatex text.tex in Fedora 37, it works fine:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-07>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2021/03/23 v3.7o configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem12.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) [1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}] (./test.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 9544 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

But, if I run the same command if Fedora 38-beta, I get the following error

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-12-17>
! Use of \@tempa doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> u
                 ndefined
l.2 
    
?
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: latex 2022-06-01 and l3layer 2022-12-17 looks like an odd combination. I would have expected latex 2022-11-01 here.

Comment: Has been raised as a Fedora bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2178523

Comment: it seems that you really have a mix of versions, your main latex format doesn't define \stockwidth, but you have a firstaid which tries to handle its existence.  You can try `\newdimen\stockheight \newdimen\stockwidth` at the begin of the document, but Fedora should correct that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was an issue with the Fedora 38 Beta packaging mildly incompatible versions of certain TL components, which was fixed in advance of the release of Fedora 38 (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2178523).